# Finding maximum/minimum using Lagrange multiplier

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier, qcqp

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{extremize} & xy+2yz+3zx\\ \text{subject to} & x^2+y^2+z^2=1\end{array}$$

How to find the maximum/minimum using Lagrange multipliers?

Context: This is not a homework problem, my friend and I often make up problems to challenge each other. We both love Maths and we are both students.

I have improved my answer based on user247327's suggestion, and I have found the maximum value of 2.056545.Thank you for contributing ideas to my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "Lagrange multipliers" you look at $F(x)= xy+ 2yz+ 3xz+ \lambda(x^2+ y^2+ z^2- 1)$.

Then
$F_x= y+ 3z+ 2x\lambda= 0$
$F_y= x+ 2z+ 2y\lambda= 0$
$F_z= 2y+ 3x+ 2z\lambda= 0$ and
$F_\lambda= x^2+ y^2+ z^2- 1= 0$.

Since a value for $\lambda$ is not required for the answer, I would eliminate it from the first three equation.  Multiply both sides of the first equation by y to get $y^2+ 3yz+ xy\lambda= 0$ and multiply both sides of the second equation by x to get $x^2+  
 2xz+ xy\lambda= 0$.  Now subtract: $y^2- x^2+ 3yz- 2xz= 0$.

Similarly, multiply the first equation by z to get $yz+ 3z^2+ 2xz\lambda= 0$ and multiply the third equation by x to get $2xy+ x^2+ 2xz\lambda= 0$.  Now subtract: $yz- 2xy+ 3z^2- x^2= 0$.

We now have three equations
$y^2- x^2+ 3yz- 2xz= 0$
$yz- 2xy+ 3z^2- x^2= 0$ and
$x^2+ y^2+ z^2= 1$ to solve for x, y, and z.

Comment: Thank you! When I simplify the equations as you suggested, I got the answer -0.6 as the maximum/minimum value. My friend told me the answer (maximum) should be approx 2.0565. Does it mean using the Lagrange Multiplier cannot find the maximum value?

Comment: are you sure -0.6 is correct? Considering the objective function I doubt that a maximum is attained at a negative value. Take, for instance, $x,y,z=1/\sqrt 3$. This choice satisfies the condition and results in a positive value of the objective function

Comment: I realised I did not use the correct way to solve it on Wolfram Alpha, that's why I did not get the correct answer. Now I found all the x, y and z values are positive, and have reached the solution of 2.0655. Thank you very much for your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

$$ x y + 2 y z + 3 z x = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}^\top \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac12 & \frac32 \\ \frac12 & 0 & 1 \\ \frac32 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix} \leq \lambda_{\max } \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac12 & \frac32 \\ \frac12 & 0 & 1 \\ \frac32 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \approx \color{blue}{2.05655}$$

Comment: Thank you! My friend also used this method to solve. What is the method called?

Comment: @ClaireS. I don't know but it is related to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem).

Comment: Ok. Thanks! ^_^